# Three.js Move camera or two different cameras

Tags: camera, three.js

I have a scene of say a coloured cube with the red side facing the camera and blue side on the far side. I want to click the "End" key and have the camera now facing the blue side (move the camera not the cube). Also have the option to hit the "Home" key to reverse the above, so it then moves back to the red side.

First thing what is the best 1 camera or 2.

Second thing I am having problems getting my keys recognised with the following code.

```
function animate()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
    update(); 
}

function update()
{
    if ( keyboard.pressed("1") )
          {  currentCamera = 1;  }
    if ( keyboard.pressed("2") )
          {  currentCamera=2;  }
}

function render()
{

   if(currentCamera==1) renderer.render( scene, camera1 );
   if(currentCamera==2) renderer.render( scene, camera2 );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know what the exact problem is with the cameras. but the keys problem is solvable. keys are handled through the use of [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener). for example:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    var key = event.keyCode;
    switch(key){
        case 49: currentCamera = 1; break;
        case 50: currentCamera = 2; break;
    }
});
```

keep in mind the `keyCode` is not the letter or number printed on the key but rather the [ascii code](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem.it now switches the camera view as well.